# System.OutOfMemoryException When trying to read 2.09 GB text file

Tags: visual-studio, out-of-memory

`System.OutOfMemoryException` When trying to read 2.09 GB text file

I am trying to read a txt file which consists of millions of lines. I am using this method.

```
string[] srLines= File.ReadAllLines("my_file.txt");
```

I have 16 GB DDR3 RAM memory. What is the solution? Thank you.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Have you verified that you are building your application as an x64 app?

Comment: why would you load entire contents at once?

Comment: problem solved with converting application to 64 bit. because exe is using over 5.5 gb ram :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set your target to be 64bit as well?

In all cases .NET processes have a limit of memory allocatable per object (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx), I am not sure if that changed with .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my 64Bit machine in VS2012.
I changed "project settings" --> "Build" --> Uncheck "Prefer 32-bit"
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason that you really need to have all those lines in memory all at once, you could also use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader) and read the file sequentially. Your algorithm might be more complex but you will use much less memory.